# Intentando crear un script que detecte palindromos

Tags: javascript

Soy super novato en Javascript y trataba de realizar un script el cual detectase palíndromos, y por más que lo repaso no logro ver el error. Siempre me salta el else y me dice que no es palindromo.Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor? Siento si es algo muy obvio, pero soy prácticamente lego en la materia. GRACIAS de antemano! Adjunto código:

```
function palindromo(texto) {
 var x = texto.toLowerCase(); //cambio el texto a minusculas
 var a = x.replace(/\s/g, ''); //quito los espacios
 var b = a.split("");  //lo convierto en array
 var c = a.split("").reverse(); //invierto el array en otra variable

//intento comparar las variables previamente creadas
 if (b == c) {
   document.write("Esto SI es un palindromo");
 } else {
   document.write("Esto NO es un palindromo..");
 }

}

palindromo(prompt("Introduce tu frase para saber si es un palindromo"));
```

Answer (score 6):

En JavaScript, dos instancias de objetos nunca son iguales, incluso si tienen el mismo contenido. Entonces tus `arrays` no son mismos.
En lugar de comprobar si los dos `arrays` coinciden puedes comprobar si la palabra y la palabra invertida coinciden.

```js
function palindromo(texto) {
  const x = texto.toLowerCase(); //cambio el texto a minusculas
  const a = x.replace(/\s/g, ''); //quito los espacios
  const c = a.split("").reverse().join(""); //invierto el array y cambiar a una palabra

  if (a === c) {
    document.write("Esto SI es un palindromo");
  } else {
    document.write("Esto NO es un palindromo..");
  }

}

palindromo(prompt("Introduce tu frase para saber si es un palindromo"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cont = 0;
var limite = b.length;

for(var i = 0; i<limite;i++)
{
   if(b[i] == c[i])
   {
      cont++;
   }
}

if(cont == limite)
{
   //imprime palindromo
}
else
{
   //imprime no palindromo
}
```

Tu código no da el resultado esperado por qué estás comparando las direcciones de memoria de los arreglos, pero lo que debes hacer es hacer un ciclo que recorra desde 0 hasta la última posición de los arreglos y pregunte si los elementos de esas posiciones son iguales, de serlo incremento la variable cont, la cual me va a guardar los caracteres iguales de ambos arreglos, por ultimo pregunto si cont == limite, donde límite es el tamaño del arreglo de ser iguales quiere decir que todas las posiciones de ambos arreglos son iguales por tanto es palindromo, de no ser iguales pues no es palindromo

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta@Japv. Entonces no es necesario quitar los espacios? No es lo mismo "aman a Panamá" que "amanap a nama".Por lo que he entendido con tu solución se iría comparando posición por posición del input, pero cuando llegase a un espacio daría que no es palíndromo, cuando si lo es.  No?

Comment: Te dije que eso lo dejaba a tu consideración, no obstante el código funciona, editare mi respuesta y quitare lo referente a los espacios

Comment: Es verdad que no es lo mismo quitar los espacios que no quitarlos, da diferentes resultados, pero de eso te tenías que dar cuenta tu, que eres el que hace el ejercicio, en el código que te puse yo no pongo nada que tenga que ver con los espacios lo de los espacios te lo dije como una observación, te repito el código funciona